# Is latency the only concern for using AWS Simple Email Service in a different region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have all my Applications in Asia Pacific (Sydney), and want to use SES. but unfortunately SES is not available in APAC at the moment, if i use SES for my emails i understand there will be some latency, but is there anything apart from this that i need to be concerned about when using SES cross region?

Also, am i better off using a linux EC2 instance as a mail relay instead of using SES, atleast until it is supported in the region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off using SES cross region, than using an EC2 instance for outgoing email. Email traffic coming from EC2 instances are often flagged as SPAM, even if it wasn't done by you; perhaps because of whoever had the ip address before you, or perhaps because another email provider has blacklisted the entire ec2 ip range.

Other than latency (which should have mininmal actual affect on you or the recipient), I don't see any downside in using SES from a different region.

Comment: What about cross-region traffic cost? was reading a bit and found that it could cost more for cross region traffic. we don't have a million emails to send out a month, so it wont be significant but still a factor. thanks for the answer BTW.